# Select single text character from body element with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, dom, text

Using regex javascript or Jquery, how do i select a lone character or in the body element? We have noticed that there's a random "s" at the bottom of our site, after the footer. We have no idea where it came from -it's really bizarre because it's in the `body` element, but it's not tied to any child element. it's just floating there in between some script tags.

[image: screenshot of the 's' after the footer]

screenshot of the 's' after the footer

---

[image: here is the 's' in the DOM in between scripts]

here is the 's' in the DOM in between scripts

---

It might be from a plugin - but in the meantime, we were hoping we could hide this until we find the culprit.

I'm trying to select the element first with this in the console, but I've had no success.

`jQuery('body').filter( function(){ return /([s]$)/g.test( jQuery(this).text() ) } )`

However, I can't select this element.. does anyone know how I can do this? Thanks so much

Comment: Maybe your `s` character was added by adding a new script tag, and then saving with CTRL + S?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 that's a really good idea and very plausable.. how could you write a regex expression to search for that `s` character?

Comment: Is your source transpiled/compiled to a built JavaScript file? Otherwise just check the raw source code and search with a regex for `>\s*[s]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `s` is the the start of the string after the closing script tag and is the only text on that line, you could use a capturing group and use that group `$1` in the replacement:

```
(<\/script>\s*\n)s$
```

- `(` Capturing group

  - `<\/script>\s\n` Match closing script tag followed by 0+ times a whitespace char and a newline
- `)` Close capturing group
- `s` Match `s`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xywBn4/1)

```js
const s = `<script type="text/javascript"><\/script>
s`;

console.log(s.replace(/(<\/script>\s*\n)s$/, "$1"));
```

Comment: The devtools usually show text nodes in quotes. But the quotes just indicate a text node not actual quotes in the source.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Thank you for your comment. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is php, try to search something like this in the beginning of the php file.
This is a piece of code that will be just echoed, not executed.

```
s<?php
```